# insert row if one with equal value does not already exist

Tags: sqlite, sql-insert, exists, unique-constraint

I'm trying to do an insert into table if the table doesn't already contain a field with a specified value. For this I am using this command: `INSERT INTO zyprexa (NULL,'hello',0,0,0) SELECT date WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM zyprexa WHERE date='hello');` so it should insert a row with the values `null,'hello',0,0,0`. And then if it is executed again it should not do anything since there is already a row with the date value "hello". But it gives me a syntax error and doesn't run it even the first time. All the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO zyprexa (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) 
SELECT NULL, 'hello', 0, 0, 0 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM zyprexa WHERE date = 'hello');
```

where `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5` are the names of the columns that will receive the values (for example `col2` should be `date`).

If you want the column `date` to be unique in your table, you should define it as such:

```
CREATE TABLE zyprexa  (
......
date TEXT UNIQUE,
......
);
```

and then you can execute `INSERT` statements with `INSERT OR IGNORE`, in which case if you try to insert a new row with a `date` (or any other column defined as unique) that already exists in the table, the insertion will fail (without any error):

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO zyprexa (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) 
VALUES (NULL, 'hello', 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: great. it worked!